# How to retrieve date from a given input

Tags: python

i have a DataFrame and i need to create a column that will have the Date in Date format. The other dataframe columns contain Month, Year and Day of the month. Below is the example.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the sample dataframe so that the dataset can be recreated? Like df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for if you want to keep the literal day of the month:

```
import pandas as pd    
from datetime import datetime


df['Date'] = df['Birth Year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['Birth Month'].astype(str) + "-" + df['Day'].astype(str)
```

[image]

If you want to have the actual date you would have to add the actual day and run it like so:

```
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime(row['Birth Year'], row['Birth Month'], row['Day']), axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
df = #Your input dataframe

#Extract the day, month and year into a single column
df["Date"] = df['Day'].astype(str).str[0] + df["Birth Month"].map(str) + df["Birth Year"].map(str)

#Convert it into a string format consisiting of the date
df["Date"] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%d%m%y').date())
#Now convert the column into pandas datetime format
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

### Output:

print(df)

```
   Birth Month  Birth Year           Day       Date
0            5          88    1st Monday 1988-05-01
1           10          87   3rd Tuesday 1987-10-03
2           12          87  2nd Saturday 1987-02-21
3            1          88   1st Tuesday 1988-01-01
4            2          88    1st Monday 1988-02-01
```

print(df.dtypes)

```
Birth Month             int64
Birth Year              int64
Day                    object
Date            datetime64[ns] #Desired datetime format of pandas dataframe
```